# req.body returning "Forbidden"

Tags: node.js, express, railway.js

In my node.js  express app I'm submitting a form, to an action on a controller.
All this controller does is:

```
send(req.body)
```

(I'm using RailwayJS (but that's not all that important to this question I don't think)
I'm doing this is to get the values in the form

However, it comes back as 'Forbidden'

If I restart node, and refresh the page (confirming i want to post back) then I get the desired result...

Any idea how to get the values of the form without restarting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to 'protect from forgery' beforeFilter. Do you pass authencity_token to your post?

Possible solution: `skipBeforeFiler('protect from forgery');` -- it disables CSRF protection
Better solution: use form_for helper, or pass authencity_token manually. Check apidocs to learn more about CSRF protection: http://jsdoc.info/1602/express-on-railway/helpers.html#instance/csrf_tag